# Is there a Java equivalent for .Net System.Data?

Tags: java, .net, database

Is there a Java package providing funcionality like the .Net System.Data namespace ?
Specificaly the DataSet and Adaptor classes ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [java.util](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html) for the collections.
[java.sql](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html) for databases.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent to ADO.NET is JDBC. You can get the flavor of it here:

http://www.heimetli.ch/jdbc/JDBCQuery.html

Answer (score 0):

ADO.NET is a framework with multiple uses, and DataSet is one of the main abstractions. Tell us more about what you want to achieve, and I'm sure somebody will find a Java framework for that purpose.

If you want a simple way to map Java objects to a data backend (like XML files), take a look at some of the POJO (Plain Old Java Object) frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

[Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/) is a popular framework in the Java world.  Pretty simple mapping of objects to tables and lots more.

Comment: Hibernate is anything but simple.

Comment: I agree with skaffman, Hibernate has a lot of features but whether or not its complexity is justified is a subject of much debate.